# Why don't Outlook 2010 rules find the same messages that normal searches do?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search, email-filter

I have a rule in Outlook 2010 that moves messages containing certain French words to my Junk folder:

[image: Image of Rule Text]

As you can see, one of the words is "découvrez". If I search for "découvrez" in my Deleted Items folder, ten messages come up. If I then run the rule on my Deleted Items folder, none of the ten are moved to my Junk E-mail folder. However, the first time I ran the rule on my Deleted Items folder, several messages were moved, so some messages containing "découvrez" were detected when the rule first ran.

Why does searching for messages containing "découvrez" find messages that my rule doesn't seem to find? It's not an issue of case sensitivity, because several messages that searching finds but the rule does not are spelled exactly like the search term. (Searching itself seems to be case insensitive.)

Comment: Do you see the same discrepancy with words that are confined to just the 26 letters of the English alphabet too?

Comment: I seem to recall having a similar problem with "normal" words before, but I haven't checked. Either way, I'd like to know why I'm getting different results for two kinds of searches for a single search term. I'd like to believe that a search is a search is a search.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with "désinscrire" too? True, there should be no discrepancy ideally. Hopefully someone who's faced this can suggest a fix or workaround if it's just a configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem with "désinscrire".